# Adding NSMenuItems to a NSMenu in code

Tags: macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have added a menu named Resources to the main menu bar and dragged an outlet named resourcesMenu to the app delegate.

When I attempted to add a method addResources.., auto completion suggested: -(void)addResourcesMenu:(NSSet *)objects.  Is this just a suggested name for the method or is there some Apple code somewhere that I should be cooperating with?  Is there documentation that would clarify this?

Thanks

Comment: Seriously, why is there no answer to this question.